# Ways to know if model has been eager loaded

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to know if there is a way to know if a model that is being called by a trait is **eager loaded** or **called directly**.

For ex: We have 2 models **Users** & **Posts**.

**Posts** model has a trait, inside of which I would like to do certain **actions** when **Posts** model is being **called directly** and something completely different when it is being **eager loaded** from **Users** Model

I searched online for a solution to this questing but did not find anything related to it. I also used **dd($model)** to see if there are any fields that describe if model has been **eager loaded** or not but no luck there. It would be nice if laravel had something that lets us know if the model has been **eager loaded** or it is **being called directly**.

Comment: In the collection you can check which model is eager loaded. Try to study laravel collection.

Comment: Inside a trait I need tk know if model is being eager loaded or it is being called directly, Imagine User eager loads Post Model, or there is an api call to get all posts. Inside a trait I need to know if it is being called from api route so I can do something different from when it is being loaded from User model

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) PHP dev tools. Clockwork gives you an insight into your application runtime - including **database queries** request data, etc.
[image]

or Laravel [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

This package includes some custom collectors:

- QueryCollector: Show all queries, including binding + timing
- RouteCollector: Show information about the current Route.
- etc...

Comment: I don't need it to debug things, I need it so I can customise actions based on the way model is being called. Ps. I use laravel telescope to do those things you mentioned